# python column replacement and fillnna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
df:
A   B_x B_y C_x C_y
R1  0   3   6   7
R2  NAN 4   8   9
R3  2   5   NAN 2
```

I am looking to replace NAN values from columns with _x with corresponding columns of _y.

I cannot use absolute names like B_x and B_y since the column names are dynamically derived from previous code and i have no control over it.

Right now i am using the following:

```
ens_prefix is a variable which holds values of column along with _x
ens_prefix_1 is a variable which holds values of column along with _y

    df[ens_prefix].fillna(df[ens_prefix_1], inplace=True)   # replace values of NAN from _x column with _y
    df = df.filter(regex=r'.*(?<!_y)$')                     # remove columns with _y suffix
    df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip('_x')                # strip suffix at the right end only.
```

Expected output:

```
    A    B    C
0  R1  0.0  6.0
1  R2  4.0  8.0
2  R3  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: ```df.replace({"NAN":np.nan}).bfill(axis=1)```

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I prefer use `replace` in columns names instead `strip`, because `strip` should aslo remove all last `x`, `y` values not only after `_`, but also before `_`.

Solution use[`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with replaced `_x` to empty strings with selected last `_y` and removed columns by `_y` in last step:

```
df = (df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace('_x', ''))
        .fillna(df.filter(regex='_y$')
                  .rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace('_y', '')))
        .filter(regex=r'.*(?<!_y)$'))
print (df)
    A    B    C
0  R1  0.0  6.0
1  R2  4.0  8.0
2  R3  2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate over all the columns in `df` find the column which ends with `_x`, then fill the `nan` value in this column with the corresponding column having `_y` as suffix:

```
for col in df.columns[:]:
    if col.endswith('_x'):
        df[col.rstrip('_x')] = df.pop(col).fillna(df.pop(col.rstrip('_x') + '_y'))
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
    A   B   C
0   R1  0   6
1   R2  4   8
2   R3  2   2
```

Comment: Downvoter, Why the downvote, any specific reason for downvoting?